# Why isn't winsock delivering WSAESHUTDOWN here?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, shutdown, winsock2

Minimal, reproducable example:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <thread>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


constexpr int BUF_SZ = 512;
void RecvThread(SOCKET sock)
{
    int iResult = 0;
    char buf[BUF_SZ] = {};

    iResult = recv(sock, buf, BUF_SZ, 0);

    assert(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR);
    assert(WSAGetLastError() == WSAESHUTDOWN);
}


int main()
{
    int iResult;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    assert(iResult == 0);

    SOCKET sock_1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    assert(sock_1 != INVALID_SOCKET);

    SOCKET sock_2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    assert(sock_2 != INVALID_SOCKET);

    in_addr loopback = {};
    loopback.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 = 127;
    loopback.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 = 0;
    loopback.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 = 0;
    loopback.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4 = 1;

    sockaddr_in addr_1 = {};
    addr_1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_1.sin_port = 51234;
    addr_1.sin_addr = loopback;

    iResult = bind(sock_1, (sockaddr const*)&addr_1, sizeof addr_1);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);

    sockaddr_in addr_2 = {};
    addr_2.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_2.sin_port = 51235;
    addr_2.sin_addr = loopback;

    iResult = bind(sock_2, (sockaddr const*)&addr_2, sizeof addr_2);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);

    std::thread t1(RecvThread, sock_1);
    std::thread t2(RecvThread, sock_2);

    iResult = shutdown(sock_1, SD_BOTH);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);
    t1.join(); // after shutdown, join the recv thread

    iResult = shutdown(sock_2, SD_BOTH);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);
    t2.join(); // after shutdown, join the recv thread

    // note: everything works if we delay t1.join() until after shutdown(sock_2)

    iResult = closesocket(sock_1);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);

    iResult = closesocket(sock_2);
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);

    iResult = WSACleanup();
    assert(iResult != SOCKET_ERROR);

    return 0;
}
```

This hangs when attempting to join the recv thread, which is blocked on `recv`. If all created sockets have been `shutdown`, `WSAESHUTDOWN` is delivered and the program exits cleanly.

Am I doing something wrong, misunderstand how `shutdown` is supposed to work, or is this a Windows bug?

Since this may be a Windows bug, I'm on Microsoft Windows Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1165).

I expect to receive `WSAESHUTDOWN` when I `shutdown` the socket, and that occurs when I `shutdown` both sockets, but if I `shutdown` one socket and then block on the thread join, the program hangs. It's this hang that I'm attempting to diagnose.

UPDATE: the original question used `recv`, but apparently this is problematic with UDP sockets, and the lack of shutdown error occurs with either `recv` or `recvfrom`.

Comment: `shutdown()` on a UDP socket doesn't send anything over the wire, so it doen't affect the peer's `recv()` or `recvfrom()` or whatever he is reading with. All it does is prevent you from sending again on the socket. It's not TCP, it doesn't deliver a FIN.

Comment: @user207421 `shutdown()` may not send anything to a peer (besides, there is no peer being assigned in this code anyway, as there is no call to `connect()`), but it does still affect the socket that `recv/from()` is being called on. This code is calling `shutdown()` on both sockets.

Comment: I'm unsure if correcting the error of using `recv` in the question (rather than `recvfrom`) changes it too much, but I've opted to correct the question rather than ask a new near-duplicate. The original question of why `WAESHUTDOWN` isn't getting raised here stands, using the correct `recv` operation. In fact, I'm somewhat consistently seeing the first socket be shutdown in the debugger, but not the second.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `recv()` on a UDP socket unless you first call `connect()` to statically associate a remote peer with the socket.  Otherwise, `recv()` can't return any datagrams, since it won't know which ones are from the desired peer, so it will discard everything.

Since you are not calling `connect()`, you should be getting a `WSAENOTCONN` error in both threads.

If you are not going to `connect()` the sockets, you need to use `recvfrom()` instead.

Comment: Ah, I wish I hadn't "simplified" to `recv`; the same lack of `WSAESHUTDOWN` occurs with `recvfrom`.

Comment: @CAD97 in that case, the code looks fine to me, and the behavior should act as expected, so it must be a Windows bug. That said, a simple solution would be to send a packet to the socket's port to unblock `recvfrom()`, or use `WSARecvFrom()` with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` so you can wait on a secondary event you can signal when needed.

Comment: If you add that tidbit to your answer I'll happily mark it as the solution. (Comments are transient etc)